# Angular 1.5 Component Bindings with controller not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-components, angular-components

so My binding is working below up to before I use the controller to do a certain function. I can do $ctrl.value and the value of the data is showing up on the view.

when I try to implement a controller, then the value becomes undefined. Why is this happening?

Current component:

```js
module.component('ratingComponent',{

    templateUrl:'jay-movies/movie-rating.component.html',
    bindings: {
        value:"<"
    },
    controllerAs:'vm',
    controller: ($scope)=>{

        let vm = this;

        $scope.entries = new Array($scope.value);
        console.log($scope.entries);

    }
})
```

```html
<span ng-repeat="stars in entries track by $index ">

*
</span>
```

```js
<tr ng-repeat="m in data">
   <td>{{m.title}}</td>
   <td>{{m.length}}</td>
   <td>
    <rating-Component value= "m.rating" ></rating-Component>
   </td>
   <td>
```

so before I insert my own controller, I test to see if I am getting the value by doing $ctrl.value, and it works (JSON data from a local JSON file). I am using the controller to display a number that is coming (simple digits in an array) to match * symbol, so it would look like ratings. I am adding other code, it might help to see what I am trying to do, but the issue I believe is with my controller. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKpFM.jpg)

Comment: try this `ng-repeat="stars in vm.entries track by $index "`

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes mentioned below.

1. Don't mix `$scope` inside a scope when you're using `controllerAs` syntax. Here you're using component, so you shouldn't be consider using `$scope`
2. `bindings`'s `value` will be available inside controller context. So do use `vm.value` inspite of `$scope.value`.
3. Use `$onInit` lifecylce hook when assigning value on component startup.
4. Now use `vm.entries` on instead of only `entries`.

**Controller**

```
controller: ()=>{
    let vm = this;
    $onInit(){
       vm.entries = new Array(vm.value);
       onsole.log(vm.entries);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right. I did not pay attention to use of `$scope` . thanks for mention it.like always your answer is complete :)

Comment: i forgot to mention in the comment that i tried using controller first before scope, its the same vm,entries still undefined. i assume below is the correct sintax for $onInit, it throwing error with your code. controllerAs:'vm',
    controller: ()=>{
        let vm = this;
        vm.$onInit= ()=>{
            vm.entries = new Array(vm.value);
            console.log(vm.entries);
        }
    }

Comment: @jaychacko could you add plunker/fiddle of the same, then it would be helpful for me to dig deeper

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1are8lw8cd1nghn/AAB33vLHxQ3fj7yqP_WROii_a?dl=0                   thats the whole code, plunker didnt want to work today i guess:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot put `vm` before scope object. 
so try this in template.

```
ng-repeat="stars in vm.entries track by $index "
```

Comment: Partially true.. for making this happen OP has to do several changes.. Please check below :)

Comment: i bind entries with $scope.entries , so i shouldn't have to use the controller vm right ?. That way i get to see the view, using vm , my view is not coming up . when using scope view comes up but without the data from value, because both scope.entries and vm.entries giving me undefinded when consoling it

Comment: do you use for main controller from `controllerAs` syntax? I mean  for `<tr ng-repeat="m in data">`

Comment: that was an attempt to fix this problem , maybe use controller instead of scope, but that created more problem the view is also blcoked with first issue of 'value' data is undefined , so at the moment i was just using scope, did not use the controller as.  i

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1are8lw8cd1nghn/AAB33vLHxQ3fj7yqP_WROii_a?dl=0           thats my whole code, if you have time